# Azure SQL DB status monitor

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way how can I get alert (notification/email) when our Azure Database is down? Maybe something with datacenter, or DB is in the Deprecated status.

So far, I found one query, that we might use

```
SELECT 'myDatabase status is:' AS Description, 
       ISNULL((SELECT state_desc 
               FROM sys.databases WITH (NOLOCK) 
               WHERE name ='DB Name'),'Not Found') AS [DBStatus]
```

Maybe I should create some background job. But I was thinking, if there is something built in that we can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive an alert based on monitoring metrics for, or events on, your Azure services.
You can opt :

- Receive Service Notifications
- Track Service Health

[image]

For an alert rule on a metric value, when the value of a specified metric crosses a threshold assigned, the alert rule becomes active and can send a notification. For an alert rule on events, a rule can send a notification on every event, or, only when a certain number of events happen.

When you create an alert rule, you can select options to send an email notification to the service administrator and co-administrators or to another administrator that you can specify. A notification email is sent when the rule becomes active, and when an alert condition is resolved.

**References :**

**[How to: Receive Alert Notifications and Manage Alert Rules in Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn306638.aspx)**

**[How can Azure notify me when my primary database becomes unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425611/how-can-azure-notify-me-when-my-primary-database-becomes-unavailable)**

Comment: yes, i was checking that, but couldn't figure it out, what option should i use to find out, if DB is not accessible. Maybe Failed Connections? Couldn't find more details.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the previous user posted, metric based alerts are probably the closest built-in solution but it doesn't fully address your scenario. If the database is down, the associated metrics are likely not guaranteed to be functional.

Your best bet is to setup a cron job to issue some synthetic SQL query via either Azure Scheduler or Azure Logic Apps.

Longer term, the platform would provide this built-in alerting capability via Resource Health.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-health/resource-health-overview